# vertical jquery carousel with multiple rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel

i'm looking for a jquery carousel plugin that supports multiple rows in vertical direction. I would like to drag & drop the individual items so i can not put multiple items in one list-item.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[Gallerific](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/)**.

Example gallery located **[here](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-2.html)**.